# Rotary encoder interface to Raspberry Pi python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, event-handling, interrupt, gpio

I have been looking into reading a 2-bit mechanical rotary encoder in `quadrature` in Python with a Raspberry Pi for simple human-interface purposes (think volume control or menu navigation).

I am using a `Keyes KY-040` module for initial tests but will probably switch to something like [this](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/pec11R.pdf).

I've found the two below pages, and have rolled my own solution based on the guidance within.

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=140250
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=126753&p

I am using [event detection](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) on both rising and falling edges on both encoder channels and incrementing a counter based on the move, which I understand gives me quadrature performance over the links above.

My callback for A-channel trigger looks like this:

```
def A_trig(enc_A):
    time.sleep(.001)
    A = GPIO.input(enc_A)
    B = GPIO.input(enc_B)
    global count
    if A:
        if not B:
            count += 1
        else:
            count -= 1
    else:
        if B:
            count += 1
        else:
            count -= 1
```

There is a likewise callback for the B channel, though it increments in the other direction. In terms of debounce, I have added `100nF` caps across each channel and use a soft debounce time of `2 ms`.

This code seems quite logical to me and should handle quadrature encoder reading well, provided the event detection works without a hitch.

The performance is... satisfactory, but it is not as smooth as I would like - I often get missed moves (based on detente feel).

I've got a reasonable amount of experience using [Paul Stoffregen's Encoder Library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Encoder.html) on Arduino for near identical applications with good success.

I understand `MCUs` and `RPis` are very different beasts but I can't help think there is better performance to be had here without too much scaling-up of the hardware.

The question is, is this the best approach to reading a human-interface encoder in this case?

Some other ideas I've had are to use an intermediary `MCU` to handle the encoder and have it report the count number to the `RPi` on request, or even look into a quadrature counter chip.

There is also the [py-gaugette](https://github.com/guyc/py-gaugette) library to try, and some further debugging (hard and soft) of my current approach to be tried, but I am interested to get some input from some hardware/software experts on how they'd do it in the meantime.